# Writing a while loop with an undetermined argument

Tags: python

I've looked for an answer for this for a couple days now but no luck.

I am trying to read a file on python that contains many lines of codes (~3457 lines) and a lot of those lines are repeated. Here is the code I have:

```
variable = 0
while(variable < 4000):
    with open("/home/user/code/file_to_read_from") as fin:
        lines = (line.rstrip() for line in fin)
        unique_lines = OrderedDict.fromkeys( (line for line in lines if line) )
        u_l_f = unique_lines.keys()[variable]
        b = open("/home/user/code/file_to_write_to", 'a')
        b.write("{}\n".format(u_l_f))
    variable += 1
```

This code works although it gives me the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

How would I create a while loop that would not give me this error specially if I don't know how many lines the file has?

Comment: What is the relation between var_test  and variable??

Comment: Why are you doing 4000 times the same thing? You'll end up having 4000 times the contents of `file_to_read_from` in `file_to_write_to` (as you're appending).

Comment: oops just edited it @Xoce웃Пepeúpa

Comment: sorry just edited it @zmo

Comment: You should post the complete Traceback with your questions.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `while` loop? If you want to write out the unique lines from the file, just use a `for` loop over the `OrderedDict`'s keys.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you *need* a while loop. This expression, ```(line for line in lines if line)```, will iterate over every line in the file without regard to its length.

Comment: I did think of doing that but I don't really know how I could do that effectively (I'm a noob) @Blckknght

Comment: Have a look at [7.2 Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and [5.6 Looping Techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) in the Tutorial of the documentation.

Comment: FYI, as a rule, in python, when you're doing while loop with a manually handled index, you're definitely doing something wrong. It should either be a `for i in range()` loop, or you should do it in a totally different way (like iterating over an `Iterable`…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, let's forget a minute that this code breaks with python yelling at you. And let's analyze a bit the logic of your algorithm. What your doing, in pseudocode is the following:

```
do 4000 times, with index "i":
    lines ← read the whole 'file_to_read_from' file as array
    unique_lines ← get rid of all the duplicate lines
    u_l_f ← get one line from unique_lines at index i
    append u_l_f into 'file_to_write_to'
```

so in the end, you're repeating 4000 times the operation of reading the whole file, each time you write one line in the output.

Another issue in your code is that you're using the context (with statement) for the input file, which is nice, but you're not using it for the output file.

And not only you'll open 4000 times the output file, making that many file descriptors (actually less, as the file will get closed when garbage collected, but it's not instantaneous), but within the `close()` method of a file you're writing to, it's doing a `flush()` which makes sure that the few bytes that might still be in the buffer actually gets written, so that when you're reopening the file, you're not loosing any bytes.

---

That being said, if you're getting an error, it's likely to be because your index `variable` is higher than the length of the `unique_lines` list, but that's just a guess, as it really depends on the size of your input file, and how many unique non-empty lines you have in that file.

The right way to do what you want is to read once the file, and iterate over the `unique_lines` list to write each line in the `file_to_write_to` file:

```
    with open("/home/user/code/file_to_read_from") as fin:
        unique_lines = OrderedDict()
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line:
                unique_lines[line] = None
        with open("/home/user/code/file_to_write_to", 'w') as b:
            for line in unique_lines.keys():
                b.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

And there you iterate only twice over the file (once to read the input file and store it in the ordereddict, and the second time to write the lines in the output file.

And you can make it happen in one go, by using a set:

```
    with open("/home/user/code/file_to_read_from") as fin:
        with open("/home/user/code/file_to_write_to", 'w') as fout:
            seen_lines = set() # create the set
            for line in fin:
                line = line.rstrip()
                if line and line not in seen_lines: # if the line hasn't been seen
                    seen_lines.add(line) # mark it as seen
                    fout.write("{}\n".format(line)) # write it
```

Here, I'm opening only once each file, both with context managers, so that they properly get closed once the algorithm has finished its work. Then it is iterating only once over the file lines (`for line in fin`), checking for unicity and emptiness and writing the line as it is iterating.

In algorithmics, there's a topic called [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory), that defines the [`O()` — *big O* — notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). It's a metric to evaluate how the algorithm will behave, as the number of input will grow in terms of time and space complexity. Given that:

- `n` is the number of lines in the file,
- that `n=4000`, that you magically guessed before running your algorithm,

your code is `O(n²)` — which means that for each line you're reading, you're reading again every line, whereas mine is `O(n)`, because I'm only iterating once over all the files.

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Thank you very much for that great explanation! It also helped me for the next part of the code that I couldn't get!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
 u_l_f = unique_lines.keys()[var_test]  //(...must be **variable** here... )
```

you are reading an array and trying to get the element at position `var_test` (...must be variable here... )

BUT you are not even sure if the file has so many lines (4000), maybe your file has only 100 lines, so you shouldnt hardcode the while loop

---

try something like reading the file line by line

## Example:

```
myArray = [] 
with open(PATH,'r') as fileReader :
    for line in fileReader :
        myArray.append(line)
```

Comment: Sorry I edited the code but it should be variable.
How would I go by not hard coding the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a run at this, however it's not particularly clear what your end goal is

```
with open("/home/user/code/file_to_read_from") as fin:
    uniqueLines = {}
    # read through the file line by line
    for line in fin.xreadlines():
        line = line.rstrip()
        # look for duplicates
        if(uniqueLines.has_key(line)):
            #not neccessary but will generate some stats on the repeats
            uniqueLines[line] += 1
        else:
            uniqueLines[line] = 1
    #uniqueLines now has the all the keys - you can use the OrderedDict to preserve the order
    b = open("/home/user/code/file_to_write_to", 'a')
    for line in uniqueLines.keys():
        b.write(line+'\n')
    b.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved like that:

```
with open("/home/user/code/file_to_read_from") as fin:
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in fin)
    unique_lines = OrderedDict.fromkeys( (line for line in lines if line) )

with open("/home/user/code/file_to_write_to", 'a') as fout:
    for line in unique_lines:    
        fout.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

That code reads a file, lists all the unique lines and put those in the output file.